# Execute an array of Javascript promises one after one resolved

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, bluebird, reduce

I wonder if there is a way that I can execute an array of promises waterfally? i.e. I want the next promise not to start until the current promise is resolved.

My test:

```
import Promise from 'bluebird'

describe('promises waterfall', () => {
  const result = []
  function doItLater(val, time = 50) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        result.push(val)
        resolve(val)
      }, time)
    })
  }

  it('execute promises one after one resolved', done => {
    result.push(1)
    const promiseList = [doItLater('a', 100),doItLater('b', 1),doItLater('c')]
    result.push(2)

    Promise.each(
      promiseList,
      (output) => {
        result.push(output + '-outputted')
      }
    )
      .then(
        () => {
          result.push(3)
          console.log(result)
          expect(result).to.eql([ 1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a-outputted', 'b-outputted', 'c-outputted', 3 ])
          done()
        }
      )
  })
})
```

---

**Update**

Sorry if I have made it too confusing. I'm asking how I can make my test pass. Currently my test fails - the actual result is in wrong order:

```
[ 1,
  2,
  'b',
  'c',
  'a',
  'a-outputted',
  'b-outputted',
  'c-outputted',
  3 ]
```

Comment: @SkinnyJ, OP is asking about blocking the `Promise` until previous one is resolved..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create promises like this

```
[doItLater('a', 100),doItLater('b', 1),doItLater('c')]
```

they are already executing asynchronously. There is no way of controlling their order of execution.

You can use [`Promise.reduce`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.reduce.html) for your case, like this

```
Promise.reduce([['a', 100], ['b', 1], ['c']], function(res, args) {
    return doItLater.apply(null, args).then(function(output) {
        res.push(output + '-outputted');
        return res;
    });
}, result)
.then(function(accumulatedResult) {
    ....
});
```

Now, we are creating promises one by one, after the previous promise is resolved and we are accumulating the result in `res` (which is actually `result`). When all the promises are resolved, the `accumulatedResult` will have all the values.

---

**Note:** It is strongly recommended *NOT* to share data between functions. Please make sure that you have compelling reasons to do so, if you have to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question - how is a promise triggered? Is it triggered by `()` or by `.then()`? Because if the promises are executed when I assign them to array `[doItLater('a', 100),doItLater('b', 1),doItLater('c')]` as you said, then shouldn't the actual result have each of the `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'` appears twice? e.g. something like `[1, b, c, a, 2, b, c, a, ...]`, because I have executed the promises twice?

Comment: When you do `doItLater('a', 100)`, the async operation starts and the promise object is returned. So when you do `promiseList`, we are simply dealing with the promise objects returned by `doItLater`, the async operations are not triggered again.

Comment: I think OP is actually looking for `mapSeries`, not `reduce`

Comment: @Bergi I actually have also tried `mapSeries`, it gives me exactly the same wrong order result. I probably have used it in a wrong way tho.

Comment: @Bergi Possibly, but looking at the example, the results are gathered in `result`. I was really not sure what to suggest, but then the question was tagged with `reduce`, so I went with that.

Comment: @IvanWang That is because of the reason which we were discussing above.

Comment: Another question, this could be a little off topic. I don't like the look of `doItLater.apply(null, args)`. Do you know of any other cleaner solution, or 3rd party lib that can help me avoid `.apply null`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @IvanWang As you have used ES6 syntax in your question, you could use the spread operator, like this `doItLater(...args)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Promisse waterfall pattern
var promises = [1,2,3].map((guid)=>{
    return (param)=> {
      console.log("param", param);
      var id = guid;
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        // resolve in a random amount of time
        setTimeout(function () {
          resolve(id);
        }, (Math.random() * 1.5 | 0) * 1000);
      });
    }
}).reduce(function (acc, curr, index) {
  return acc.then(function (res) {
    return curr(res[index-1]).then(function (result) {
      console.log("result", result);
      res.push(result);
      return res;
    });
  });
}, Promise.resolve([]));
promises.then(console.log);
```